# Google analytics Fragment screen views

Tags: android, android-fragments, google-analytics

My app has one activity and many fragments. I've read about ALL topics about this question, and no one worked as I can see.
I've tried with both ga v3 and v4, following the

The problem is that BOTH ways, analytics retrieve only the first call I perform. When I change fragment, and perform another call in the same way, the 'real-time' analytics doesn't change.
Both snippets are executed from onStart() method in every fragment.

```
    // Using ga v4
    Tracker t = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this).getTracker("UA-XXXX-1");
    t.setScreenName("/home");
    t.send(new HitBuilders.AppViewBuilder().build());

    // Using ga v3
    EasyTracker _tracker = EasyTracker.getInstance(getActivity());
    _tracker.set(Fields.SCREEN_NAME, "/discover");
    _tracker.send(MapBuilder.createAppView().build());
```

Any suggestion would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually I think I might found the way to make it works. Reading the documentation: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/dispatch

> By default, data is dispatched from the Google Analytics SDK for
>   Android every **30 minutes**.

Yes, my thoughts were "What???? 30 minutes? Is not suppose to be real time?" Anyway, reading a bit more:

> To set the dispatch period programmatically:

```
// Set the dispatch period in seconds.
GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this).setLocalDispatchPeriod(15);
```

> To set the dispatch period in the XML configuration file:

```
<integer name="ga_dispatchPeriod">30</integer>
```

What more...

> Setting a negative value will disable periodic dispatch, requiring that you use manual dispatch if you want to send any data to Google Analytics.

```
// Disable periodic dispatch by setting dispatch period to a value less than 1.
GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this).setLocalDispatchPeriod(0);
```

Ok, maybe you have found a controversial here, negative value or less than 1? I tried, it is less than 1! (0 or negative number will disable periodic dispatch).

If you prefer then the manual dispatch, that would be, for example:

```
tracker.setScreenName(TAG);
tracker.send(new HitBuilders.AppViewBuilder().build());
GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(getActivity().getBaseContext()).dispatchLocalHits();
```

Notice that you can call dispatchLocalHits() whenever you want (even make a button that calls that function). By the way, that piece of code it's on my fragments (in the onResume() method).

Also the documentation says:

> If a user loses network access or quits your app while there are still hits waiting to be >dispatched, those hits are persisted in local storage. They will be dispatched the next >time your app is running and dispatch is called.

But I was not sure if this applies to both manual and periodic dispatch. I tried it, both seem to be working :)